# VBA: Application.VLookup on Filtered Range returns same value after first filtered row

Tags: vba, excel

This is a simplified version of a much larger workbook, which demonstrates the issue I'm having;

[VBA Filtered vLookup Example.xlsm](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33942680/VBA%20Filtered%20vLookup%20Example.xlsm)

```
Sub LookupMonths()
    Set objValues = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Results").Range("A2", "A13")
    Set objResult = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Results").Range("B2", "B13")
    Set objSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Source").Range("A1", "B13")
    objResult.Value = Application.VLookup(objValues, objSource, 2, False)
End Sub
```

As the original workbook has thousands of rows, I'd opted to use a range as the first argument (lookup_value).  This works fine if the data is unfiltered.  However I have a number of rows I don't wish to update, so these are filtered out based on their contents.  In this example, I've manually filtered out months 3, 8 and 11.  As you can see, this results in a number of months returning January/February only.

I've tried creating a filtered range based on **xlCellTypeVisible** (as per the below) but this doesn't appear to have any impact.

```
Set objFilteredResult = objResult.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
objFilteredResult.Value = Application.VLookup(objValues, objSource, 2, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the lookup performed for the hidden rows as well, you can set the range of `objValues` and `objResult` to only include visible cells in the range, then perform the lookup for each cell in the filtered range:

```
Set objValues = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Results").Range("A2", "A13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set objResult = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Results").Range("B2", "B13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set objSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Source").Range("A1", "B13")

For Each c In objResult
    c.Value = Application.VLookup(c.Offset(0, -1), objSource, 2, False)
Next
```

EDIT: Note that you don't need to set objValues at all in this case.

Comment: Yes, this would work, and it's something I tried, but as mentioned the original workbook has thousands of rows, so looping through each cell in the range is a massive performance hit, and simply not an option I'm afraid. Unfiltered, setting the values of the entire objValues range simultaneously is almost instant, even with thousands of rows.

Comment: Understandable. Unfortunately, VLookup simply doesn't support using filtered ranges. A way around this would be to use a hidden column (or sheet) and copy the filtered range to this column, then set that range as the lookup values.